# Find all the controls that are visible to the user

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I find all the controls on a form that are currently visible to the user? i.e. list all the controls that can be tabbed to and are not hidden from view (e.g. on a non-visible tab sheet).

Comment: The part before the 'i.e.' doesn't exactly match the part after it. For instance, before it, the 'controls' need not be windowed, and they can be disabled. After it, they have to be both windowed and enabled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you write that you want to list the controls that you can tab to, I assume you are talking about windowed controls.

Then you can do simply

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Components[i] is TWinControl then
      if TWinControl(Components[i]).CanFocus then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Components[i].Name)
end;
```

if you know that the form owns all its children  and no other controls. Otherwise, you have to do

```
procedure AddVisibleChildren(Parent: TWinControl; Memo: TMemo);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Parent.ControlCount - 1 do
    if Parent.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
      if TWinControl(Parent.Controls[i]).CanFocus then
      begin
        Memo.Lines.Add(Parent.Controls[i].Name);
        AddVisibleChildren(TWinControl(Parent.Controls[i]), Memo);
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddVisibleChildren(Self, Memo1);
end;
```